# Getting Segmentation Fault with Simple Perl Program

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault

I have been using Cory Watson's Chart::Clicker Perl module in a marketing program for a 3+ years without any issues until last week.

I'm including a very simple example of my code. This program fails when it gets to the write_output command. I'm experiencing the same problem in my actual program.

*The actual program hasn't been modified at all. This problem appeared out of the blue*.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Chart::Clicker;

my $cc = Chart::Clicker->new;

my @values = (42, 25, 86, 23, 2, 19, 103, 12, 54, 9);
$cc->add_data('Sales', \@values);

$cc->write_output('/home/test/public_html/tmp/foo.png');
```

When I run this program on my server, it reports a "Segmentation fault" error. If I comment out this line of code:

```
$cc->write_output('/home/test/public_html/tmp/foo.png');
```

no error is reported.

Any ideas on what might be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Did the permissions change?  Check the permissions on the file `/home/test/public_html/tmp/foo.png` and the parent directories.

Comment: Does this path exists on server?

Comment: Was anything else upgraded on the server? The docs for Chart::Clicker mentions issues with CentOS and something called Cairo. You may want to check if you have the right version of Cairo. Also, consider contacting the author of the module.

Comment: I thought it might be a permissions issue too, so I temporarily set the tmp folder to 777. No joy. The path does exist on the server.

Comment: Chart::Clicker does have many dependencies of which Cairo is one. Cairo is a 2D vector library. I'm running on RHEL5. Chart::Clicker is notoriously difficult to configure on RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who offered help.

We ended up reinstalling Perl on the server (its a dedicated, fully managed server - the host opted to do this because the Perl module installer on CPanel wasn't responding correctly). After doing this, test.cgi reported a variety of new compilation errors all related to Chart::Clicker.

We reinstalled several of the Chart::Clicker dependencies and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Some additional info. I pursued root cause with our host. His comment follows: "I'm 100% certain the issue this year was with a cPanel update. They switched from using a custom-compiled version of Perl 5.8.8 to utilizing the perl shipped with RHEL. This has broken all sorts of modules across a number of client systems over the past few weeks."